# how to make keyevent that perform a click only if there is text

Tags: java, android, actionlistener, keyevent

so i am trying to setup a key event for a new device that have a scan button i had it to work before with the virtual keyboard but i can't get it to work with the hardware key

working on the other device with virtual keyboard on version 4.1 but also do not work on the new device which is 5.1

```
shelfnumberbox.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL
                && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            btn_aprove.performClick();
        }
        return false;

    }
});
}
```

what i am trying to getting to work

```
shelfnumberbox.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL
                    && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_A) {
                btn_aprove.performClick();
            }
            return false;

        }
    });

}
```

the api's fully functional hardware keyevent

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_A:
        if(isOnResume && scanCase != START_TEST_CASE){
            mDecoderMgr.dispatchScanKeyEvent(event);
        }
        isScanKeyDown = false;
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if there is text before performing the click event:

```
if (v.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
    btn_aprove.performClick();
}
```

As such:

```
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL
            && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (v.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
            btn_aprove.performClick();
        }
    }
```

Comment: so there is no way to getting it to work with the key event?

Comment: Updated answer. Just wrap `performClick` with the if statement, or add it to the parent if statement.